# MongoDB: how to aggregate from multiple collections with same aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I'm trying to get aggregations with same aggregation pipeline including `$match` and `$group` operations from multiple collections.

For example,

with a `users` collection and collections of `questions`, `answers` and `comments` where every document has `authorId` and `created_at` field,

```
db = [
    'users': [{ _id: 123 }, { _id: 456} ],
    'questions': [
        { authorId: ObjectId('123'), createdAt: ISODate('2022-09-01T00:00:00Z') },
        { authorId: ObjectId('456'), createdAt: ISODate('2022-09-05T00:00:00Z') },
    ],

    'answers': [
        { authorId: ObjectId('123'), createdAt: ISODate('2022-09-05T08:00:00Z') },
        { authorId: ObjectId('456'), createdAt: ISODate('2022-09-01T08:00:00Z') },
    ],
    'comments': [
        { authorId: ObjectId('123'), createdAt: ISODate('2022-09-01T16:00:00Z') },
        { authorId: ObjectId('456'), createdAt: ISODate('2022-09-05T16:00:00Z') },
    ],
]
```

I want to get counts of documents from each collections with `created_at` between a given range and grouped by `authorId`.
A desired aggregation result may look like below. The `_id`s here are ObjectIds of documents in `users` collection.

```
\\ match: { createdAt: { $gt: ISODate('2022-09-03T00:00:00Z) } }
[
    { _id: ObjectId('123'), questionCount: 0, answerCount: 1, commentCount: 0 }, 
    { _id: ObjectId('456'), questionCount: 1, answerCount: 0, commentCount: 1 }
]
```

Currently, I am running aggregation below for each collection, combining the results in the backend service. (I am using Spring Data MongoDB Reactive.) This seems very inefficient.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { 
        created_at: { $gt: ISODate('2022-09-03T00:00:00Z') }
    }},
    { $group : {
        _id: '$authorId',
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }}
])
```

How can I get the desired result with one aggregation?

I thought `$unionWith` or `$lookup` may help but I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, using $lookup, here we join users, with all the three collections one-by-one, and then calculate the count:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "questions",
      "let": {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$gt": [
                    "$createdAt",
                    ISODate("2022-09-03T00:00:00Z")
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$$id",
                    "$authorId"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "questions"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "answers",
      "let": {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$gt": [
                    "$createdAt",
                    ISODate("2022-09-03T00:00:00Z")
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$$id",
                    "$authorId"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "answers"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "comments",
      "let": {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$gt": [
                    "$createdAt",
                    ISODate("2022-09-03T00:00:00Z")
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$$id",
                    "$authorId"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "comments"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "questionCount": {
        "$size": "$questions"
      },
      "answersCount": {
        "$size": "$answers"
      },
      "commentsCount": {
        "$size": "$comments"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dUow4vlVk0K). In the above query, we use pipelined form of $lookup, to perform join on some custom logic. Learn more about [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-multiple-joins-and-a-correlated-subquery-with--lookup) here.

Another way is this, perform normal lookup and then filter out the elements:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "questions",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "authorId",
      "as": "questions"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "answers",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "authorId",
      "as": "answers"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "comments",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "authorId",
      "as": "comments"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      questionCount: {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$questions",
            "as": "item",
            "cond": {
              "$gt": [
                "$$item.createdAt",
                ISODate("2022-09-03T00:00:00Z")
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      answerCount: {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$answers",
            "as": "item",
            "cond": {
              "$gt": [
                "$$item.createdAt",
                ISODate("2022-09-03T00:00:00Z")
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      commentsCount: {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$comments",
            "as": "item",
            "cond": {
              "$gt": [
                "$$item.createdAt",
                ISODate("2022-09-03T00:00:00Z")
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M8tce4eGTTG).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where should I put `$match`(or any filtering operation for `created_at`) in the pipeline?

Comment: It should be the first stage, before `$lookup`. Updated the answer, as well.

Comment: Can I put filter before joining documents with `$lookup`? As I mentioned in the question, I am trying to filter documents in other collections than `users`.

Comment: ok, that can be done, within $lookup only. Can you add some sample documents from all collections to the question itself? I will update the query accordingly.

Comment: Cool, I will update the answer, shortly

Comment: Thanks a lot, however it seems Spring Data MongoDB doesn't support $lookup with let/pipeline. Is there any other query for the same result? (I am currently using custom AggregationOperation for this query)

Comment: Yess there is a way, I think. It will be a bit tedious. Let me create a query for it.

Comment: Added a new query in the answer